# FFMpeg decode settings via C API?

Tags: android, linux, ffmpeg

Does anyone know of any decode settings via the FFMpeg C API? For some reason after updating the quality of the decoded video has gone down.

Either via post-processing filters or simply decode options?

Anyone?